# Skype Android: how to remove skype online status from notification?

Tags: skype

Skype keeps on showing my online status in the notifications. It's a irritating thing for me. Please help me to get rid of it.

Comment: Go to settings, Apps, Skype, untick Show notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, because i cannot upload screenshot at comment so i upload the screenshot at answer box.
Go to Skype setting, select Notification and turn off Skype status notification.

[image]

Comment: Your welcome, glad i can help.